# How to login into oracle database using encrypted username and password?

Tags: apache-camel, jasypt

I encrypted username and password of oracle database using camel-jasypt component. How to login to oracle database using the encrypted values?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to wire up a Datasource and I further guess you are using spring for that.

Then, it's probably easier to use plain jasypt than the Camel component (as you wire up the DataSource out of the Camel route).

Something like this (uses the same approach as is done in Apache ActiveMQ, refered to from the [Camel-jasypt documentation](http://camel.apache.org/jasypt.html)). That said, you can of course also use the Camel jasypt component for stuff you need to encrypt inside the route itself.

```
<bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
  <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES"/>
  <property name="password" value="activemq"/>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
  <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" /> 
  <property name="location" value="file:/conf/credentials-enc.properties"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.oracle.Whatever"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:foo://hostname/database"/>
  <property name="username" value="user"/>
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Petter for reply...i am trying to access database credentials  from properties file like this..                                <bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
     destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}"/>
   <property name="url"  value="${db.url}"/>
   <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
   <property name="password"  value="${db.password}"/>
 </bean>

Comment: i am getting error like this   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initDatabase' defined in file [C:\Users\761285\Downloads\working database oracle\camel-example-sql\target\classes\META-INF\spring\camel-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '${db.driverClassName}'